# MVC Cascading Dropdownlist with JQuery ajax and Json format is resulting selected value as 'undefined'

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am just a beginner with MVC and JQuery.
I am trying to create a simple cascading dropdownlist application with Country and State as  a two dropdowns. I have used a JQuery ajax as a scripting to handle Dropdown change event.

But when I selects any country from a dropdown my event fires correctly, but I unable to get the selected value as it returns 'undefined' value.

Can anyone help me in this.

I am sharing my code as per below.

Below are the functions defined in the controller part

```
public ActionResult Index()
{   
   return View();
}

public JsonResult GetCountries()
{
    return Json(db.Countries.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public JsonResult GetStatesByCountryId(string countryId)
{
     int Id = Convert.ToInt32(countryId);
     var states = from a in db.States where a.CountryID == Id select a;
     return Json(states);
}
```

Below is the Index.cshtml part

```
<div>

    <div>
        @Html.DropDownList("dropdownCountry", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a country", new { @style = "width:250px;" })
    </div>

    <div style="margin-top:50px;">
        @Html.DropDownList("dropdownState", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a state", new { @style = "width:250px;" })
    </div>


</div>


<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/home/getcountries",
                    datatype: "Json",
                    success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    $('#dropdownCountry').append('<option value="' + value.CountryId + '">' + value.CountryName + '</option>');
                    });
            }
        });


        $('#dropdownCountry').change(function () {
            var selectedCountryID = $('#dropdownCountry').val();

            alert(selectedCountryID);

            $('#dropdownState').empty();
                $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "/home/GetStatesByCountryId",
                       datatype: "Json",
                       data: { countryId: $('#dropdownCountry').val() },
                       success: function (data) {
                       $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                       $('#dropdownState').append('<option value="' + value.Id + '">' + value.StateName + '</option>');
                       });
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you saying `var selectedCountryID = $('#dropdownCountry').val();` returns `undefined`?

Comment: Hi Stephen, Your are write, I am getting return unidentified at $('#dropdownCountry').val()

Comment: Can you see the Json in the response (browser dev tools)? If so, then it's just malformed jQuery logic.

Comment: Nothing in your code suggests it could be undefined. What are the values of `value.CountryId` in the first ajax function? Also (not related) but use `var selectedCountryID = $(this).val();` and `data: { countryId: selectedCountryID  },` and change the method to `GetStatesByCountryId(int countryId)`

Comment: Hi Stephen,  I have already tried doing $(this).val() but it doesn't worked. I have some findings of this issue. When I tried to just passing Country as List<SelectListItem> from the Index controller using ViewBag, It worked as expected. But when I passes the data using Json result defined in function GetCountries() is doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Hi Tez, could you please tell me something more about Json in the response (browser dev tool).  Thanks

Comment: Hi Tez, could you please tell me something more about Json in the response(browser dev tool).   Thanks

Comment: HI Guys, I have some more findings, it may help to understand the issue more clearly,  When I bound data to dropdown Json GetCountries() function and I try to check view page source I found the html generated for dtopdown countries is                                      <select id="dropdownCountry" name="dropdownCountry" style="width:250px;"><option value="">Please select a country</option>
</select>                                                                                                           But when I bind data using Index view and List<SelectListItem> the data binds properly,

Comment: Please check below page source                                                             <select id="dropdownCountry" name="dropdownCountry"><option value="">Select Country</option>
<option value="1">India</option>
<option value="2">United States</option>
<option value="3">United Kingdome</option>
</select>
Hope this will help

Comment: And if you want to do this correctly, study [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) for a working example

Comment: Hi Stephen, The solution you have provided is working fine. Thank you for your help, and also thank you for the suggestions. Have a nice day and Happy coding.

Comment: @Tez Thank you for your help.